# Parts of the foot

Tags: vocabulary, translation

### I'm looking for the parts of the foot in Korean.

[image]

### I know a few of them:

- Foot  `발`
- Toe `발가락`
- Big Toe `엄지 발가락`
- Ankle `발목`

---

### added from solutions

- Heel `발꿈치`
- Ball `발볼`
- Bridge `발등`
- Sole `발바닥`

### Updated Parts of Foot

[image]

Comment: i'm updating the picture with the answers provided by @user17915

Comment: Great to update the picture, but I wonder if the updated picture would fit better edited into user17915's answer, or below the horizontal rule with the other words 'added from solutions'? At the moment, the question starts with its own answer, which looks a bit unusual....

Comment: @topomorto i think you're right...i'll take care of that tomorrow, sir.   thx!

Comment: **i am still missing "Bridge" or "top of foot".  `발위` maybe?  and i think Achilles may very well be just `아킬레스` but i'm still holding out for something Korean.**

Comment: 발등 is the upper part of the foot (so probably "bridge"?), i.e., the part that hurts if someone steps on your foot.  I'm not sure what is "instep arch", but the part shown in the figure is definitely not 발등.

Comment: @jick hmm, curious, i'll update that photo until we get a consensus.  would you mind providing a complete list as a solution, please?

Comment: @jick instep and arch are two different adjacent parts, if I understand this correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some information I was able to dig up:

ankle -> 발목
instep -> 발등
arch -> ? (could not confirm but think it's simply called 아치)
toe -> 발가락 (fingers of the foot)
ball -> 발볼
achilles -> same as arch, transliterated into 아킬레스
heel -> 발꿈치
bridge -> ?
sole -> 발바닥

Names of individual fingers:
Not sure but the Korean wikipedia for [발가락](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%B0%9C%EA%B0%80%EB%9D%BD) lists them as

> 엄지와 작은 4개의 발가락

So either they do not have any specific names or the names are possibly consistent with the name of the corresponding digit in the hand
(for reference, the fingers of the hand are called 엄지손가락, 집게손가락, 가운뎃손가락, 약손가락 and 새끼손가락 )

However, that might not be true. For example, from Korean wikipedia for [약손가락](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%95%BD%EC%86%90%EA%B0%80%EB%9D%BD),

> 옛날에 약물을 물에 달일 때 약손가락을 사용한 것에서 유래했다는 설이 있다

Hence 약손가락 is called so because it was traditionally the finger used to add ingredients to water while preparing medicine, a meaning which would not make sense when referring to the corresponding digit on the foot.

My guess is that they don't have common individual names.

Sources:
[발](http://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=938840&cid=51006&categoryId=51006#TABLE_OF_CONTENT3)
[발뒤꿈치](http://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=3547625&cid=58583&categoryId=58594)
DioDict4 (smartphone dictionary app)

---

Some more links:
[손가락의 명칭](http://blog.daum.net/bgu54/5014)

[발가락의 명칭](https://blog.naver.com/papa7272/50177058729)

Comment: this is a good start. I learned the fingers as 엄지, 검지, 중지, 약지, 애지 but I'm sure there are variants. I do want to try and find native Korean answers that are common, not necessarily medical.

Comment: maybe it's a followon question, but i wonder why the finger/toes use `지` and the heel uses `치`. i guess it's describing the matter itself, but i wonder what those syllables represent since as a second language learner, neither give me imagery that i'm sure native speakers benefit from.

Comment: for one thing the finger and heel are completely different parts of the foot. The suffix 지 probably has it's roots in Hanja where it is a synonym for finger, and 엄, 검, 중, 약, 애 are the names of the specific digits. Notice also that 중지 has the character 중 meaning centre, and this particular finger is also known as 가운뎃손가락 (middle finger). Similarly 애지 has the character 애 which means baby, which would give it the same meaning as 새끼손가락.

Comment: @WEBjuju 지 corresponds to Hanja 指(for fingers)/趾(for toes), while ~꿈치 is a native Korean bound morpheme and shouldn't be separated into 꿈 and
 치. The origin of ~꿈치 is unclear, but it may be a derivative of 굽 (which also means 'heel', e.g. 발굽); also see "elbow" (팔꿈치). Related vocabulary for 굽 are to do with curves (e.g. 굽이).